# Is there a way to annotate this django object computer property?

Tags: django, django-models

I have an django Model named `Payment` that I want to filter by a computed property.

```
class Payment(Model):
   ...other fields
   terms = PositiveIntegerField(help_text='days')
   issued_date = DateField()
```

then I have this property to calcutate the payment_date

```
@property
def payment(self):
    return self.issued_date + datetime.timedelta(days=self.terms)
```

I tried to annotate it with something like this:

```
Payment.objects.annotate(due_date=ExpressionWrapper(F('issued_date') + F('terms'), output_field=DateField()))
```

but unfortunately it's not working. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this works:

```
Payment.objects.annotate(due_date=ExpressionWrapper(F('issued_date') + F('terms'), output_field=DateField()))
```

The problem was that `due_date` already exist as a property and changing this to a different name fixed the error.

```
Payment.objects.annotate(date_due=...rest of the expression here)
```